# Merge two different json object in extjs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Let's say my first json object is

```
  "jvtdata":{
    "tranid":"100001",
    "trandate":"Sun Jan 20 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)",
    "trantype":"f"
  }
```

and my second data is

```
 "detail" : [
   {
      "id": "1",
      "obj": "data1"
   },
   {
      "id": "2",
      "obj": "data2"
   },
   {
      "id": "3",
      "obj": "data3"
   }

]
```

how do I make it like this in extjs 4?

```
  "jvtdata":{
    "tranid":"100001",
    "trandate":"Sun Jan 20 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)",
    "trantype":"f",
    "detail" : [
   {
      "id": "1",
      "obj": "data1"
   },
   {
      "id": "2",
      "obj": "data2"
   },
   {
      "id": "3",
      "obj": "data3"
   }

]
  }
```

Comment: Hi, any answer below helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your comment on another answer, here is what you are looking for(I think?):

```
var details = Ext.Array.pluck(store_jvdtl.data.items, 'data');
var jvtData = Ext.Array.pluck(store_jvhdr.data.items, 'data')[0];
jvtData["details"] = details;
jvtData = Ext.encode(jvtData);
```

Comment: `Ext.pluck` is deprecated since ExtJS 4.0.0, use `Ext.Array.pluck`instead

Comment: Updated according to #Darin Kolev

Answer (score 2):

This is not an ExtJS specific question.

If you truly have two Objects `jvtdata` and `detail` (and not a JSON string, which you can easily turn into an Object) you can simply do the following:

```
jvtdata.detail = detail
```

**EDIT**: See console for this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FXT9k/

Comment: actually those two json object came was created from this:

    var jvdetailData = Ext.encode({ details:Ext.pluck(store_jvdtl.data.items, 'data')});
                            var jvheaderData = Ext.encode({ jvtdata : Ext.pluck(store_jvhdr.data.items, 'data')[0]});

I tried what you did and it didnt work for me

Answer (score 2):

[Ext.apply](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-apply) might be what you're looking for.

```
var first = {
    "jvtdata":{
        "tranid":"100001",
        "trandate":"Sun Jan 20 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)",
        "trantype":"f"
    }
};
var second = {
    "detail" : [{
        "id": "1",
        "obj": "data1"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "obj": "data2"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "obj": "data3"
    }]
};
var merged = {
    jvtdata: Ext.apply(first.jvtdata, second)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the merge method:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-merge

Answer (score 0):

Here is comparing [the function](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Object) for ExtJS:

```
Ext.Object.equals(object1, object2)
```